# How to get the selected value of a dropdown inside panel?

Tags: 7, javascript, panels

I have an exposed filter inside the panel.

I want to filter the taxonomy term. For that I add "Content: Has taxonomy term (exposed)" field.

I need to get the selected value in js.

```
Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    var tid = $('#edit-tid').val();
    alert(tid);

  }
};
```

In alert I am getting "All" rather than the selected `tid`, as shown in this image:

[image]

Comment: Check `onchange` event inside `attach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply little trick and my issue solved. Used default taxonomy search and hide it.

```
(function($) {

Drupal.behaviors.tushar_1 = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('#edit-shs-term-node-tid-depth').change(function(){
      var eid = $('#edit-shs-term-node-tid-depth').val();
      $('#edit-tid ').val(eid);
    });
  }
};

})(jQuery);
```

Solved my issue.

Comment: I "think" that you found this solution thanks to the hint in the comment from "Sibiraj PR" (below your question). If that's the case, then I "recommend" (not more then that ...) to also add something like "**Credits to [Sibaraj PR](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/6508/sibiraj-pr)**".